# Guitar Patterns Major Third Tuning Part 3

Tags: combinatorics, combinations, recreational-mathematics

As I was looking for possible string groupings for fingering chord shapes I came across a few unique set of string sets that would allow new types of chords to be played. For this unique set of string combinations I'm looking for the number of possible **unique** chord fingering combinations I can make. If I learn this set of string combination I would by now figure out all the possibilities of 4 note unique chord shapes of my Guitar (tuned in Major Thirds). So this would be my Last Last question (seriously!). Here is this set of Strings

```
            . . . .
            . . . .
            . . . .
            . . . .
            . . . .
```

In this set there is actually 5 strings across the fretboard (4 frets only). Strings are horizontal. Frets are Vertical. We're omitting the middle third string for this analysis. Here are chords that are acceptable

```
            . X . .              X . . .
            . X . .              . X . .

            X . . .              . . . X
            X . . .              X . . .
```

The X's are the notes of the Chords.

Here are five rules that must be accounted for.

1) No chords that have notes exclusive in frets 1 & 3 and also frets 2 & 4. They are not counted in this analysis. Here are the examples:

```
 . . X .                    . X . .
 X . . .                    . X . .

 X . . .                    . . . X
 . . X .                    . . . X
```

2) No repeated shapes transposed sideways in a different place. Its necessary to have one shape but I don't want see a repeat(s) of that same chord shape counted in the list of possibilities (pretty redundant).

```
 . X . .             . . X .
 . X . .             . . X .

 X . . .             . X . .
 X . . .             . X . .

   Okay              Not Okay
```

3) The chord must always have 4 notes.

4) No multiple notes in the same string. (Its not how the instrument works)

5) This last rule is unique. Take a look a these

```
 X . . .       . . . .        . . . .       . . . X
 . . . .       X . . .        . . X .       X . . .

 X . . .       . . . .        . . . .       . . . X
 . . . .       X . . .        . . X .       . . X .

                                           Not Allowed
```

The first three charts shows note doubling. Strings 1 and 4, and also strings 2 and 5 cannot have notes on the **same** fret. an example chord in the far right is shown. Chords with note doubling on strings 1 and 4 & string 2 and 5 in same fret are not allowed in this analyses.

That's pretty much it. If you can find the maximum number of combinations of chord shapes possible taking account of the 5 rules please let me know! I would very much appreciate it

(Links to First Two Parts Added)

Part One - [Guitar Pattern Question (Major Thirds Tuning)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2464801/guitar-pattern-question-major-thirds-tuning)

Part Two - [Major Thirds Tuning Guitar Pattern Question Part 2](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2467030/major-thirds-tuning-guitar-pattern-question-part-2)

P.S This is basically the same as part 2. The only difference is that now there are more instances of note doubling in chords.

EDIT: I think I just found out the answer! Its 104 chord shapes. Lots of counting and second checking for that one.. !

Comment: If this is actually the third in a sequence of related questions, I'd suggest you edit a link to each of the other questions into each question.

Comment: Just added links at the bottom!